# I like to learn to play the piano

Tags: to-infinitive

Can we use two infinitive verbs in the same clause? or Is it better to add "and" between them?

> I would like **to learn to play** the piano.
>
> I would like **to learn and to play** the piano.
>
> I would like **to learn play** the piano.

Comment: Sentence 1 is fine. Sentence 2 implies something after learn, such as *to learn music and to play....* Sentence 3 is ungrammatical.

Comment: Remember, the bare infinitive is an ACTION, and cannot be placed in a NOMINAL slot. *I would like to learn SOMETHING (nominal).  WHAT (nominal) would you like to learn?*

Comment: Sentence 3 would be grammatical if you used the gerund, "... learn playing ...", but really, sentence 1 is the one you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to learn how to play the piano

Or

> I would like to learn the piano

I would like to learn to play the piano implies that through the act of learning something you will be able to play the piano (may be there is a piano at the school or college).

I would like to learn and to play the piano implies that the two actions are unrelated.

I would like to learn play the piano doesn't make sense.